# NIFI: Unable to extract two values from a list during each iteration over a loop

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to retrieve large SQL dump between date ranges. For the same, I constructed a loop over a date list, which intends to extract adjacent fields. Unfortunately, in my case, it doesnt work as planned.

Following is my flow:

[image]
`Replace Text`: Takes flowfile content date list as `all_first_dates`
[image]

`Initialize Count`: [image]

```
While Loop:
```

[image]

```
Get first and adjacent dates:
```

[image]

However, on seeing the queue, I get the `first` and `second` as this:

[image]

Whereas, I desired as `2016-01-01` and `2016-01-02` for `first` and `second` respectively on my first iteration and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the description of the [getDelimitedField](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#getdelimitedfield) function and it's parameters:

**Description:** Parses the Subject as a delimited line of text and returns just a single field from that delimited text.

**Arguments:**

**index:** The index of the field to return. A value of 1 will return the first field, a value of 2 will return the second field, and so on.

**delimiter:** Optional argument that provides the character to use as a field separator. If not specified, a comma will be used. This value must be exactly 1 character.

...

> you are not passing the second parameter, so the coma used to split the subject, and you got the whole subject as one element in result.